# How to click element in table with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to select the available appointment

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://vadmvappointments.as.me/schedule.php?calendarID=5322490")

element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(//*[@id="step-pick-appointment"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2])

element.click()
```

Comment: You should be thanking them, they actually made it readable

Comment: im new idk how they were able to edit it...

Comment: No worries. There is an edit button that users can click to edit posts. Generally it is to fix code formatting

Answer (score 1):

Cpl things...

Your xpath is missing double quotes enclosing it...

So instead of this:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(//*[@id="step-pick-appointment"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2])
```

Use this:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='step-pick-appointment']/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]")
```

Notice how I also changed `find_elements_by_xpath` to `find_element_by_xpath`, it is a single element.

But, that link you sent returns "no available appointments", so even if the `xpath` is correct it won't work